# in C# how to choose and show random row in existing Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, xls, datareader, exceldatareader

i'm new at c# and excel coding. i want to choose a excel file and show it after that show random row or rows (need to user enter how many row user want) after user pressing a random button and it can be pop up the screen like another form or change in data grid view it doesnt matter. User can choose excel file from computer and i can show it in data grid view but stuck at random row part and cant find anything useful in internet. This is may code(i tried too much thing so maybe some not useful code lines be in the codes):

```
using ExcelDataReader;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Excel_D
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        DataTableCollection tableCollection;



        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using(OpenFileDialog openFileDialog=new OpenFileDialog() { Filter="Excel Workbook|*xlsx|Excel 97-2003 Workbook|*xls"})
            {
                if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    txtFileName.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
                    using(var stream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                        {
                            DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                            {
                                ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() { UseHeaderRow = true }
                            });
                            tableCollection = result.Tables;
                            cBoxSheet.Items.Clear();
                            foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in tableCollection)
                                cBoxSheet.Items.Add(table.TableName);


                        }   
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        Random rnd = new Random();

        public void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt = tableCollection[cBoxSheet.SelectedItem.ToString()];
            GridView.DataSource = dt;
        }

        public void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        
        }

        public void GridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

i dont know this is important or not but it is the designer part of the code:

```
namespace Excel_D
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

       
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

      
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.BtnBrowse = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.cBoxSheet = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.txtFileName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.GridView = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.GridView)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // BtnBrowse
            // 
            this.BtnBrowse.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(682, 279);
            this.BtnBrowse.Name = "BtnBrowse";
            this.BtnBrowse.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 20);
            this.BtnBrowse.TabIndex = 0;
            this.BtnBrowse.Text = "=>";
            this.BtnBrowse.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.BtnBrowse.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 279);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(58, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.label1.Text = "Dosya Adı:";
            this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
            // 
            // cBoxSheet
            // 
            this.cBoxSheet.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.cBoxSheet.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(86, 306);
            this.cBoxSheet.Name = "cBoxSheet";
            this.cBoxSheet.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
            this.cBoxSheet.TabIndex = 3;
            this.cBoxSheet.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            // 
            // txtFileName
            // 
            this.txtFileName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(86, 279);
            this.txtFileName.Name = "txtFileName";
            this.txtFileName.ReadOnly = true;
            this.txtFileName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(590, 20);
            this.txtFileName.TabIndex = 4;
            this.txtFileName.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 306);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 13);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 5;
            this.label2.Text = "Sayfa:";
            this.label2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label2_Click);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 333);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(723, 27);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 6;
            this.button1.Text = "Rastgele örneklem seçmek için tıklayın.";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click_1);
            // 
            // GridView
            // 
            this.GridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.GridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.GridView.Name = "GridView";
            this.GridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(745, 254);
            this.GridView.TabIndex = 1;
            this.GridView.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.GridView_CellContentClick);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 366);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(723, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 7;
            this.button2.Text = "Rastgele örneklem görmek için tıklayın.";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoScroll = true;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(766, 451);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtFileName);
            this.Controls.Add(this.cBoxSheet);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.GridView);
            this.Controls.Add(this.BtnBrowse);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "ExcelÖrneklem";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.GridView)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button BtnBrowse;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cBoxSheet;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtFileName;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView GridView;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do yo know how to create a random number? Simply generate a random number (within the range of the number of rows in the worksheet) and then select a row by that random index.

Comment: i know how to create random number but i dont know how to write code about range (because range is change for every excel file)